# How to use ngfor to print property of object?

Tags: json, angular

```
<div *ngFor="let article of articleList;let i = index">
                    <div class="item">
                    <div class="image-holder"
                         style="background-image: url(https://c9.io/blog/content/images/2015/07/ninja-1.jpg)">
                        <a href="https://c9.io/blog/title-wip-cloud9-shortcutfoo/"></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="title">
                        <a class="title-ref" href="#">{{article.title}}</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <div>
                            {{article.description}} <a class="text-ref" href="#">>></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-header">
                        <div class="author">
                            <img class="img-circle"
                                 src="https://c9.io/blog/content/images/2015/05/brady.jpg" />
                        </div>
                        <span class="author-name"><a class="user-ref" href="#">{{article.user.name}}</a></span>
                        <div class="time">2015-07-31</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

I can see the `article.title`, description etc. but the article.user.name is undefined. if `{{article.user}}`, it will show object.

How to get print `article.user.name` properly?

Comment: What is `desprition`? Do you mean `description`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use the **safe navigation operator** like this-

```
{{article?.user?.name}}
```

This link could give you more details: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html. See the section "safe navigation operator ( ?. ) and null property paths"

See if this helps.